# Which component sends a transaction and which component subscribes to an event?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, transactions, blockchain, events

I am working on an ethereum project but I have some doubts. I have a backend that connects to the blockchain via web3.js. To connect to the blockchain I use a geth node.
I understand that the sequence is this:

send transacrion
[image]
listen to events
[image]
my questions are:

- What is the component sending the transaction? Is it the backend component or the geth node?
- Then suppose that another smart contract in the network emits an event that I want to capture. What is the component that captures the event? Is it the backend component or the geth node?

Answer (score 4):

First question - There are two options here:

1. The **backend** forms a transaction, and **geth** signs and sends it to the Ethereum network
2. The **backend** forms and signs the transaction, and the **geth** sends it to the network

Second question - maybe 2 options:

1. The **backend** requests new blocks from the **geth**, extracts events from them and selects the necessary ones
2. The **backend** configures the event filter in the **geth** according to the parameters it needs, after which it periodically requests new events, catched by **geth**.

Comment: In my project I'm assuming the geth node belongs to the backend. The first answer is clear. In the second answer I struggle to understand the difference between the two possibilities. '**The backend requests new blocks from the geth, extracts events from them and selects the necessary ones**'. Can I listen to events using myContract.events.MyEvent () or web3.eth.subscribe ('logs',…) ;? And in the second possibility does something change?

Comment: I have updated the drawing. In the second case (events) is it right to connect the arrows in this way?

Comment: Unfortunately, I use the json rpc, so I can't tell you about the specific implementation of these options in web3. :-(
Second way - Ok